# How do I change Bool property of non-view struct from inside a View

Tags: swift, swiftui, struct, binding

I'm relatively new to Swift and learning as I try to put together a redesign of an existing airline roster app. I have a RosterView containing a ScrollView with a LazyVStack with lots of data that is iterated with a ForEach inside a Section. [Here's a screenshot of RosterView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhxj8.png). Green is the Section, red is a separate View called "CheckInRow" (which takes its data from a separate struct), and blue is each iteration from another View called "RosterItemListRow" (also data from a separate struct). All structs are currently in a separate Swift file (not a view). [Here are all the structs in that file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6HbK.png) and here's the specific code in question:

```
struct CheckIn: Identifiable, Equatable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var checkInTime: String
    var checkInPlace: String
    var checkInPossible: Bool = false
    var isCheckedIn: Bool = false // <--- THIS NEEDS TO CHANGE by user action from the View
}
```

The actual data is supposed to come from external sources down the road, for now it's just static Strings in a `getRosterData()` method inside yet another struct, like so: [image: RosterData struct with the actual data that is presented] The folded `RosterDate()` above this unfolded example from 3 December is history/previous data and `isCheckedIn` will always be `true` there. Since it's already declared false, I know I don't really need it here but I included it for clarity (red arrow).

**Now to my problem:**

A button in the "CheckInRow" view (and thereby also the root "RosterView" needs to change the `CheckIn.isCheckedIn` Bool from `false` to `true` in the CheckIn struct (line 53). Given that the date in question is not passed where the data has already set this to `true`, the default state is `false` so that this prompt will look like this when duty starts at a specific airport (ARN in this case):

[image: Check In Button]
Simplified/minimal code:

```
struct CheckInListRow: View {
    var checkIn: CheckIn // Separate struct in non-view swift file
    var checkInItems:[CheckIn] = [CheckIn]()
    
    // I've experimented here with @State and @Binding
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            // This symbol changes based on the Bool value
            Image(systemName: checkIn.isCheckedIn == true ? "clock.badge.checkmark" : "clock.badge.exclamationmark")
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                // Check-in info
                Text("Check-in/Duty start")
                    .font(.footnote)
                // Check-in time
                Text(checkIn.checkInTime)
                    .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            // Check-in button if at home base and within geo fence
            if checkIn.checkInPlace == "ARN" && checkIn.checkInPossible == true {
                Button {
                    // THIS IS WHERE MY PROBLEM IS. It has to change checkIn.isCheckedIn = true
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        // The label should change based on the external Bool value, not a private @State bool
                        Text(checkIn.isCheckedIn == false ? "Check in now" : "You are checked in")
                        Image(systemName: checkIn.isCheckedIn == true ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "arrow.right.circle.fill")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Text(checkIn.checkInPlace)
            }
        }
        .opacity(checkIn.isCheckedIn == true ? 0.4 : 1.0)
    }
}

#Preview {
    CheckInListRow(checkIn: CheckIn(checkInTime: "07:00", checkInPlace: "ARN", checkInPossible: true, isCheckedIn: false))
}
```

This is what I want to happen: Pressing the button should change the `isCheckedIn` Bool to true, which then changes a few modifiers for background, icon etc.

I have learned about `@State` and `@Binding`, `@ObservableObject` and `@EnvironmentObject` which I at least get the basics of, again I'm a beginner. But what I understand, @State and @Binding is for data flow between Views only and my Bool is not in a view. **I have tried this and got @State to work inside this view, but not to bind it to the Bool from the data source** so I have now reset it back to none of this to start fresh with hopefully your help.

Also, once the button is pressed and you are checked in, that data must be available from other subViews as well, which I've learned @EnvironmentObject is for. Using @ObservableObject must be in a class so that's going to break the functionality/connection to the history/previous data of this View when the Bool is already true.

A lot of text for a possibly fairly easy solution. I tried to explain this as clearly as I can but I'm sorry if I overcomplicated this.

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  In particular show the code of the view (not a half portion of it) and how you get/declare/pass in the `checkIn`.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the text with minimal code.

Comment: You need to setup storage of some kind. Look into CoreData.

Comment: To be able to change your checkIn in `CheckInListRow`, use `@Binding var checkIn: CheckIn`,
 and call it like this in your previous view:  `CheckInListRow(checkIn: $checkIn)`
 note the `$`, and you need to declare `@State var checkIn: CheckIn ...` for example.
 Note you are not using `checkInItems`, remove it. If you plan to use it declare it `@State var checkInItems ...`.